# Django-money. When display in template it's showing wrong format of currenncy

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a problem with displaying currency by django-money module.

In template I used 2 options:

`{{ object.balance }}` and `{% money_localize object.balance %}`.

I expected to see on website $100.00, but I got US$100.00.
The same with GBP - > GB£100.00, but I want to get £100.00.

Any ideas, why it's display this way?

My model class has field:

`balance = MoneyField(_('Balance'), max_digits=25, decimal_places=2, default=Money(0, "USD"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this template tag `format_money.py`:

```
from moneyed.localization import format_money as fm

@register.tag
def format_money
    return fm(myModel.price, locale='en_US')
```

Then in your template:

```
{% import format_money %}

...

{% format_money object.balance %}
```

Should work. Stolen [from here](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/issues/328)

Comment: Stolen link helped :)